# What is this returning 2 not 0?

Tags: c++

Here in this I don't know why does the inline function returns 2 while I have not returned any value. If i change the value of e in the function then the function returns 3. I have no idea for this please suggest.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a, b;

inline int add(int e, int d)
{
    e = 211;
    d = 312;

    //return e+d;
}

int main()
{
    a = 2; b = 3;
    int c = add(a, b);
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: You have UB as not all paths return value.

Comment: Thanks vsoftco finally this problem is off my head now. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to use a function this way. If the function prototype says that it returns something but then you forget to `return`, all bets are off. Most compilers warn you about something like this if you turn the warnings on. For example, `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang give you the warning

> Warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

More technically, when you declare a function that returns something, call that something `Foo`, then the runtime allocates some memory for that `Foo` that has to be returned. When you actually write `return some_foo;`, the returned object `some_foo` is being constructed in the allocated memory. If you forget (or don't want to write) the `return`, then the memory allocated is left un-initialized, so you end up reading from an un-initialized object, which is undefined behaviour.